# Are there suspend\resume signals in Linux?

Tags: linux, signals, hibernation

My application needs to react on hibernation mode so it can do some action on suspending and other actions on resuming. I've found some distributive-specific ways to achieve it(Upower + DBus) but didn't find anything universal. Is there a way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: This might bee something
http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/power/freezing-of-tasks.txt

Comment: @Kristofer, thanks for clue I have found more appropriate: http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/power/notifiers.txt But it seems that it is only possible in the kernel mode but I need to be notified in the user space without writing any kernel modules

Comment: Try [`systemd-inhibit`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd-inhibit.html). See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/147904/systemd-user-unit-that-depends-on-system-unit-sleep-target

Answer (score 5):

A simple solution to this is to use a self-pipe. Open up a pipe and periodically write timestamps to it. `select` on this pipe to read the timestamps and compare them to the current time. When there is a big gap, that means you have just woken up from system suspension or hibernate mode.

As for the other way around, there is not much time when the lid is closed and it flips the switch.

If you really need to act on suspend, then you will need to set powersave hooks like this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PowerManagement/ReducedPower in pm-utils. It could be as simple as

```
kill -1 `cat mypid` ; sleep 1
```

Your process would then trap SIGHUP and do what needs to be done to prepare for suspension. The sleep delays the process long enough for your program to react to the signal.

Comment: I wonder if this is still applicable to this very day

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for SIGSTOP and SIGCONT signals. You can send these to a running process like so:

```
kill -STOP pid
sleep 60
kill -CONT pid
```

Comment: This is irrelevant to the original question which is about system power modes.