# How to detect whether system is going to standby in Linux using C

Tags: c, linux

I want to know how I can detect whether the system is going to a standby mode in Linux using C. I found a message called `WM_POWERBROADCAST` in windows for that purpose, which sends this message before going to the sleep mode.

Is there any alternatives in C, for Linux?

I heard that DBus can be used for same purpose, could somebody explain it more?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6136111/are-there-suspend-resume-signals-in-linux

Comment: Well, I cant find an answer there which is useful for me

Comment: This is more a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832376/how-to-detect-pending-system-shutdown-on-linux

Comment: it's about shutdown, not standby

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally I found a solution.

We can use the pm utility for that.

If you put any shell script in /etc/pm/sleep.d folder it will be executed automatically just before the system going to sleep and after the system is resumed.

The content will be like

```
#!/bin/bash
case $1 in
suspend)
    #suspending to RAM
    /home/harikrishnan/Desktop/sleepd Sleeping
    ;;
resume)
    #resume from suspend
    sleep 3
    /home/harikrishnan/Desktop/sleepd Woken
    ;;
esac
```

here it will execute the /home/harikrishnan/Desktop/sleepd program with the arguments

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK there's no such signal in Linux, but you can try

a) `acpid` daemon hooks, if its present, acpid configs are usually in `/etc/acpi`
b) [DBus daemon hooks](https://serverfault.com/questions/191381/what-dbus-signal-is-sent-on-system-suspend), again if its presend on a system
c) reading `acpid` sources to see how it gets the signals
d) writing your own kernel module

Comment: Could you please tell me ow to use the DBus daemon hooks within a program

Comment: No, sorry, never did that.

Comment: hmm, what to do next, I tried to use wine, but in that the WM_POWERBROADCAST is not detecting