# Is there any OS function that let us check system is going to enter modern standby?

Tags: c#, c++, windows-10

I am participating in a software development. The original code used .NET's [`PowerModeChangedEventArgs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.powermodechangedeventargs?view=netframework-4.8) to determine the power mode modification. This is valid in S3 mode, but we tried to work under S0 and found that it does not trigger this event (It seems that Power mode will not be modified under modern standby?), so I would like to ask if there is any way to judge in the code that it has entered **modern standby**?

Thanks.

Comment: At least for Linux there might be a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376534/how-to-detect-whether-system-is-going-to-standby-in-linux-using-c

Comment: @AlexGeorg how is a _Linux_ sololution in any way relevant here?

Comment: @MickyD My bad, I did not notice that the TE implicitly provided the OS by mentioning .NET..

Comment: @AlexGeorg not a problem good sir

Comment: @AlexGeorg .NET Core runs on Linux, and macOS, and with some jiggery-pokery on BSD.

Comment: I don't know why people voted to close this question - the question seems straightforward to me, and I think there's an answer in this document:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/prepare-software-for-modern-standby and this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/compatibility/desktop-activity-moderator

Comment: I think I've found the answer: you need to pass a callback to `PowerRegisterSuspendResumeNotification` - though I'm unsure what parameters to expect in the callback for an `S0` event in particular.