# How to detect events like Sleep/Wake in linux

Tags: c++, ubuntu, events

I am wondering if there is any way to detect system wide events under linux such as:

- sleep
- wakeup

I need this for a project where i programmatically react to such events, but i am uncertain how and where to start. Maybe there is an api that i dont know yet.

Any hints? I would appreciate any help!

**Note** : The file "/var/log/syslog" contains the update for sleep and wakeup event, but this is not suitable for my usecase because it requires root permission to access this file.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6936702/16770846) answer your question?

Comment: No, This is not a suitable solution, it seems more like a hack.

Comment: For this kind of operating system level stuff, you should also consider asking at the [Super User](https://superuser.com/) forum. That beeing said, I would start looking at [systemd](https://systemd.io/), the "operating system layer" in Ubuntu (and many other linux distrubutions). Specifically there is the sytemd [sleep target](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.special.html#sleep.target), that you can register your service to. However, I do not think that there is a portable way of doing this (on non systemd based systems).

Comment: [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) would probably be a better forum for this question than [Super User](https://superuser.com/) since the question's directly related to Linux.

Comment: One option is to use system bus: https://askubuntu.com/questions/183516/how-do-i-detect-when-my-system-wakes-up-from-suspend-via-dbus-or-similar-in-a-py

Comment: This was crossposted to [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1493271/how-to-detect-events-like-sleep-wake-in-linux) and twice to Unix and Linux (both deleted now).  **Please choose only one site to post your question on.**

Comment: @SergeyVlasov I have tried the system bus solution in Cpp, there is a 'PrepareForSleep' signal to detect the sleep event, however, I did not find any signal for the wake event. Can u help on how to detect for wake event using Dbus?